# different getPath for different images

Tags: android, uiimageview

I need to set different getPath() for different images . Below is the sample describing getPath for one image . I am not able to understand how to use it for setting 2 images .

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
            // THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

Bitmap :-

```
public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
        bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        imgView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: we need bitmap to display image on the imageview upon button click .I am trying o find its path by the above written code.  It is working fine for 1 image display but now I want to display 2 images and I think it would take 1 more path to be build for that .

Comment: @user3467204, check my below answer, hope it will help you.

Comment: @InnocentKiller but we need to have different bitmaps for different imageviews

Comment: @user3467204, Yes we need different bitmaps.

Comment: @InnocentKiller what I am doing wrong in my code for setting bitmaps. Please check the post again . I have added those code s too.

Comment: I think you are not getting proper `filepath` for different images.

Comment: yes your are right . I am not able to set them properly. Can you please guide me how to do that .

Comment: @InnocentKiller are you able to locate error in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No actually you do not have to use different getPath for multiple images, you can have single method only for `n` number of images,

Look at this below example,

//Button's click event i am openong phone's gallery

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery(SELECT_FILE1);
            }
        });

        but2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery(SELECT_FILE2);
            }
        });
```

where here is a open gallery function.

```
public void openGallery(int req_code) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, req_code);
    }
```

and inside onActivity result i am setting different path which from which i get images,

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE1) {
                selectedPath1 = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                editText1.setText(selectedPath1);
            }
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE2) {
                selectedPath2 = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                editText2.setText(selectedPath2);
            }

        }
    }
```

and here at last

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```